# How to trigger onPress() of TouchableOpacity instead of onBlur() of AutoComplete input?

Tags: javascript, react-native, autocomplete

**JS**

```js
state = {
  autoComplete: [];
  value: ''
}

selectValue = (item) => {
  console.log('Value is selected");
}

setValue = (value) => {
  this.setState({
    value
  });
}

closeAutocomplete = () => {
  console.log("autocomplete is closed");
  this.setState({
    autoComplete: []
  });
}
```

```html
<Autocomplete 
    data={this.state.autoComplete} 
    defaultValue={this.state.value} 
    onChangeText={(value)=> this.setValue(value)} 
    onBlur={this.closeAutocomplete}
    renderItem={(item) => (
        <TouchableOpacity avatar onPress={()=> this.selectValue(item)}>
            <View>
              <Text>{item}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )} 
/>
```

On selecting any item from the autocomplete list, onPress() is not triggered instead onBlur is being triggered.

Expected: onPress must be called on click of autocomplete list items.

Issue: onBlur() is called on click of list item

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid having to click TouchableOpacity twice to trigger onPress event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58264910/how-to-avoid-having-to-click-touchableopacity-twice-to-trigger-onpress-event)