# Function inside a FlatList item does not fire when passing the renderItem as prop to the component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, event-handling, react-native-flatlist

Somehow the onPress event is not fired when pressing on a list item inside a FlatList component. I have a main component that uses a `Autocomplete` component. This `Autocomplete` component consists of a `TextInput` and `FlatList` within a `View`:

```
//Autocomplete component
//...
return (
    <View>
        <TextInput
            value={props.value}
            onChangeText={props.onChangeText}
            onFocus={props.onFocus}
            onBlur={props.onBlur}
        />
        <FlatList
            data={props.data}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            renderItem={props.renderItem}/>
    </View>
)
```

The main component passes a `renderItem` prop to the `Autocomplete` component, in which I want to call a function when pressing an item on the list:

```
//main component
//...
const selectHandler = (item) => {
    console.log("test")
};

return(
<Autocomplete
    data={filteredData}
    value={searchTerm}
    renderItem={itemData => (
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={(item) => selectHandler(item)}>
            <Text>
                some text
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity >
    )}
    onChangeText={text => setSearchTerm(text)}
    onFocus={focusHandler}
    onBlur={blurHandler}
/>
)
```

However, this `console.log("test")` never fires. What might be the reason for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid having to click TouchableOpacity twice to trigger onPress event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58264910/how-to-avoid-having-to-click-touchableopacity-twice-to-trigger-onpress-event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. Because the keyboard is open when using the `TextInput` [I need to add `keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}`](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/1117) to the `FlatList` component. I did not see that I have to click twice initially, because my `Autocomplete` component disappears `onBlur` and I thought that the `onPress` event did not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try `renderItem={() => props.renderItem}/>` in the FlatList.