# React native custom autocomplete onBlur fires before onPress

Tags: reactjs, react-native, onblur, touchableopacity, react-native-gesture-handler

I have a `TextInput` component with a List Item component that displays a list of search suggestions below it, similar to an AutoComplete. The issue is when I click one of the suggestions from the list it first fires the `onBlur` method of the `TextInput` and **requires a second press** before it fires the `onPress` method. How do I call the onPress method in one tap? I don't want it to blur if I'm pressing a dropdown list item.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think that's correct behaviour as onBlur is Callback that is called when the text input is blurred. So whenever you try to click on AutoComplete suggestions then text will be blurred first then the onPress callback will be called.

Comment: If your autocomplete is custom just put TouchableOpacity over the text and you manage your onPress inside the TouchableOpacity instead of the textInput

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid having to click TouchableOpacity twice to trigger onPress event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58264910/how-to-avoid-having-to-click-touchableopacity-twice-to-trigger-onpress-event)